# Issue with DSolve for PDE with BC

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to solve:

$u_t - 2u_{xt} = 0,\ $ where: $\ u(x,0) = \sin(x),\ \  u(0,t) = t. $

So I tried the following:

```
pde = {D[u[x, t], t] - 2 D[u[x, t], x, t] == 0, u[x, 0] == Sin[x], u[0, t] == t};
soln = DSolve[pde, u[x, t], {x, t}]
```

But I keep getting a failure to evaluate without errors, i.e.:

> DSolve[{(u^(0,1))[x,t]-2 (u^(1,1))[x,t]==0,u[x,0]==Sin[x],u[0,t]==t},u[x,t],{x,t}]

Would someone please point me out as to the solution to this issue? I have looked at the documentation and tried it different ways, but cannot resolve it. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, seems that `DSolve` is still not strong enough, then let's turn to `LaplaceTransform`:

```
pde = {D[u[x, t], t] - 2 D[u[x, t], x, t] == 0};
ic = u[x, 0] == Sin[x];
bc = u[0, t] == t;

teqn = LaplaceTransform[{pde, bc}, t, s] /. Rule @@@ {D[ic, x], ic}

tsol = u[x, t] /. 
  First@DSolve[teqn /. HoldPattern@LaplaceTransform[a_, __] :> a, u[x, t], x]

solfunc[x_, t_] = InverseLaplaceTransform[tsol, s, t]
(* E^(x/2) t + Sin[x] *)
```

Answer (score 2):

The inability of `DSolve` to produce an answer appears to be a bug.  To see that this is the case, consider

```
pde = {D[u[x, t], t] - 2 D[u[x, t], x, t] == 0, u[0, t] == t};
soln = DSolve[pde, u[x, t], {x, t}]
```

the ODE in the question with `u[x, 0] == Sin[x]` omitted.  `DSolve` yields

```
(* {{u[x, t] -> E^(x/2) t}} *)
```

which is wrong.  The correct answer is

```
(* {{u[x, t] -> E^(x/2) t + C[1][x]}} *)
```

where `C[1][x]` is an arbitrary function of `x`.  Without this term, `DSolve` cannot match the first solution obtained above to `u[x, 0] == Sin[x]`, so it is perhaps not surprising that `DSolve` returns unevaluated when attempting to solve the ODE in the question.

**Addendum - Solution Using DSolve**

As is often the case, `DSolve` can in fact solve the system in the question, if it is broken into simpler pieces.  Here, represent `D[u[x, t], t]` as `w[x,t]`.  Then,

```
Flatten@DSolve[{w[x, t] - 2 D[w[x, t], x] == 0, w[0, t] == 1}, w[x, t], {x, t}]
(* {w[x, t] -> E^(x/2)} *)
Flatten@DSolve[{D[u[x, t], t] == w[x, t] /. %, u[x, 0] == Sin[x]}, u[x, t], {x, t}]
(* {u[x, t] -> E^(x/2) t + Sin[x]} *)
```

as desired.

Comment: I guess in this case `DSolve` is solving an initial value problem of `x` i.e. it actually does something like `fo = FourierTransform[#, t, s] &; InverseFourierTransform[
 DSolve[{fo@D[u[x, t], t] - 2 fo@D[u[x, t], x, t] == 0, fo@u[0, t] == fo@t} /. 
    HoldPattern@FourierTransform[a_, __] :> a, u[x, t], x][[1, 1, -1]], s, t]`

Answer (score 1):

But with `NDSolve` it works:

```
pde = {D[u[x, t], t] - 2 D[u[x, t], x, t] == 0, u[x, 0] == Sin[x], u[0, t] == t};
soln = NDSolve[pde, u[x, t], {x, 0, 5}, {t, 0, 10}]
Plot3D[u[x, t] /. soln, {x, 0, 5}, {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however, I need the actual function as a solution. It works without BC, but introducing them leads to the issue outlined above.

Comment: Try this solution `t Exp[x/2] + Sin[x]`